# Redirecting from another page to anchors below Revolution Slider goes to low

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, web

I am working on one website with few pages. The home page has few anchors and the items in the main menu will jump on the corresponding anchor. It is working fine if you are already on the page and use the main menu. In the middle of the home page is one Revolution Slider with 4 sub items. Redirecting from another page to anchors above the slider is not a problem, but redirecting to the two anchors below the Slider is problematic. I saw that the slider is loading vertically and after the page is fully loaded it goes horizontally (as it should be). One solutions it was to use fixed height for the slider, but than is not very responsive and difficult to maintain. I am using Easy Smooth Scroll Links plugin and i tried to change the (document).ready with (window).load (JQuery version is 1.12), but nothing changed. I am using the Fortuna Theme.
The Slider is in one row with one column id: product_slider . Without the row and column the problem is still there.

Homepage : https://www.miyo.garden/
And one anchor after the slider: https://www.miyo.garden/#smarthome

Some of the plugins:
WPBakery Page Builder
Easy Smooth Scroll Links
Slider Revolution

Comment: Means Your query regarding: #smarthome link?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking, but the links are #smarthome and #cloud. If you redirect to them from another page you will see that the page is going to the bottom and not to the anchor. Only happens when redirecting from another page.